# Q: PayPal collecting the amount from the basket

Tags: paypal

I want the amount from the basket to be downloaded when I click the PayPal button and instead of the total entered. I can not seem to get it to work.

I use [this](https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client).

Anyone have any pointers?

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far and tell us why it failed

Comment: I do not know what to paste in the sandbox so money goes to my paypal account.
client: {
                sandbox: 'HERE'
            },

Answer (score 0):

You need to update below total with the total of your basket - it's not going to happen automatically.

```
     {
        amount: { total: '0.01', currency: 'USD' }
     }
```

Comment: I have already done, I ask what to give in the sandbox for money to go to my PayPal account

Comment: Have you specified a payee for your request ??